# Doctrine2 + Symfony2 Keeping history on every insert, update, delete

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing web application. The most important feature should be history(versioning) and approving inserted data by user. It means that user can see all history changes, use old version again, validate or refuse a new version, which is inserted by user without permision.

I have one table actionHistory(date,user,action,isValid) then I have e.g. Person, Address, CustomField and CustomValue tables. Person manyToMany Address. Person oneToMany CustomFields.
CustomFields oneToOne CustomValue. Every table also have a historical table.

E.G. When I am persisting person with custom field-value. I have to create person,customfield-value history tables. Copy this versions into them. Connect all historical tables and also connect with `actionHistory`.

At the beginning I've used EventListener and Lifecycle Event (postPersist,postDelete,postUpdate), but the main problem is that when I would like to add previous example I have always problem to connect these tables. I don't know which entity will persist first and when I try the second entity doesn't exist yet,etc.

```
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Address) {
        $this->addPersonHistory($em, $entity);
        $this->saveAddressHistory("UPDATE", $em, $entity, "Address");
    }
    if ($entity instanceof CustomField) {
        $this->addCustomFieldHistory($em, $entity);
        $this->saveCustomFieldHistory("UPDATE", $em, $entity, "CustomField");
    }
    if ($entity instanceof CustomValue) {
        $this->saveCustomValueHistory("UPDATE", $em, $entity, "CustomValue");
    }
    if ($entity instanceof Person) {
        $this->savePersonHistory("UPDATE", $em, $entity, "Person");
    }
}
```

Is there some better solution for this situation? Because I am stuck now, when I have to face form adding of person-customField-customValue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for exists (good news).

It's done with the `DoctrineExtensions` of Gedmo, provided by repository : https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions
The extension you need is **Loggable**, and explained here : https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md

And the best is that there is a bundle that directly implements those extensions : https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle
Explanations here : https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

Comment: Or KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors version of the same thing. https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#loggable

Comment: Thank you for an answer. If I understand well really tiny documentation of extension loggable I have to rewrite a lot of things to have exactly features that I want to have. Is there some simple solution for this behaviour in doctrine2 if I have implemented whole structure?

Comment: Loggable behavior handles only 1 table (instead of 1 table per historized entity), so you don't have to modify schema when you add an historized entity. And you don't have to deal with entity not existing yet... Here is the entity description for history : https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity/MappedSuperclass/AbstractLogEntry.php and you can override it.