# ZF2, Doctrine - get entity(document) history

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm already working with zendframework2 and doctrine2  + mongoDB (database).

I need to save the entity history on some collection but I don't know how I can save changes after editing my entity ( a document ).

I already use `UnitOfWork` for getting the document before changes and after, but the format of this document from this method (`unitOfWork->getDocumentActualData()`) has a `protected` method and I can't prepare what changes are set.

- method `computeChangeSets()` from `UnitOfWork` returns an empty array.

How I can get only changes of this entity(document).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 + Symfony2 Keeping history on every insert, update, delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378655/doctrine2-symfony2-keeping-history-on-every-insert-update-delete)

Comment: There are doctrine2 libraries/modules for such history functionality available, check the link above for reference.